# Trying to rotate on Y axis resulting in odd motion

Tags: java, 3d, camera, rendering, euler-angles

Alright, so I've made a basic program that, so far, just makes a point in 3d space, renders it to a 2d screen, and rotates the camera. Rotating on the Z axis works just fine, on the X axis works basically fine, but the motion speeds up as the point gets closer to the edge of the screen, but I think that's just because of the perspective. The weird thing is, when I try to rotate along the Y axis, instead of the point appearing to move to the left/right, it moves diagonally, which isn't what I intended.

Below is a link to a .rar file containing the Java project, please ignore the `World`and `FaceTri` classes. `Exe` is the main class.

Download the project [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?zyfjrc613vmmi42). Please tell me if you can figure out why incrementing the Y Euler Angle causes the point to appear to move diagonally.

Answer (score -1):

Wow... I'm an idiot. So it turns out the reason it was doing that is because of the position of the point; I forgot I didn't set it's Y to 0. Setting Y to 0 solved the issue. Hehehe...